# Why does using [@Name] in Excel VBA string cause error 1004?

Tags: excel, vba, xlookup

When I try to execute this statement using Excel VBA, it gives an error 1004:

```
Cells(C, 2).Value = "=IFERROR(XLOOKUP([@Name],Master_List_1[Name],Master_List_1[Email]),""error"")"
```

[image: Screen shot of error generated.]
[image: Screen shot of highlighted code.]

If I remove the brackets around @Name, it works fine.  The other brackets in the string don't cause trouble. Somehow VBA is parsing the text string and objecting to having [@Name] in there.

If I put the statement in a cell by hand (with single quotes), it works as it should. (I did forget the = sign; that's been corrected.

Comment: That code works fine for me.  However, it just puts some text in a cell, so there's no reason it would error.

Comment: ...if that's not the actual code you're using, please edit your question so we can try to help.

Comment: If that's the code you're using it shouldn't work as expected - there's no `=` at the start of the formula.  It should also be `Cells(C,2).Formula2 =`, although I think it still works with `Value`.